# SQL Server Transaction Log File Appearing In The Wrong Location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

I have a server machine that has A C and F drive. The usual transaction logs for the database are on the F drive and are of the usual size. On the C drive however, the same log files seem to be present and take up 42 GB of space on a database of size 11 GB. We had a power cut yesterday and when we tried to copy the log files, it says they are in use by the very same database that points its logs to the F drive.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You can confirm the actual files that the database is using by either checking the database properties through Management Studio, or run SELECT * FROM sys.sysfiles against the database concerned.  If the database has been restored at some time, from a backup, then it's possible the restored files may have been inadvertently restored to the "incorrect" location

Comment: I just confirmed that they point to the F drive. Not C. There does not seem to be any evidence of a backup restore.

Comment: Have you checked if you can copy the log file on F, or do they say in use for the same database? Presumably you only have one log file per database?

Comment: Run a SELECT * FROM sys.master_files against the "master" database - that will list all databases and files.  SQL doesn't really lie about using a particular file ..... plus, I'm also unsure what you're meaning by "we had a power cut yesterday and when we tried to copy the log files" ...... you're copying files from where / to where?

Comment: Did as you said @Craig . As in the electricity went and the servers shut down suddenly. The large log files that claim to be in use, we tried to copy them to an external location to see if we could back them up and before changing the names to see what happened. The table from the select statement you instructed me to run doesn't reference that path on C drive at all.

Comment: Stop the sqlserver service and see if you can then copy the file? If not it's not sqlserver that's using it.

Comment: Yes, @Stu's suggestion is the next one to try.

Comment: Ok will do it tomorrow because current users rely on it, will update this question as soon as

Comment: Alternatively look at [File Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)